# Not able to generate Jacoco reports in Android Studio multi module project

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

jdk Version:11

gradle Version:7.5

jacoco Version:0.8.8

jacoco.gradle Part of the code is as follows:

```
task jacocoTotalReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: project.getTasksByName("testDebugUnitTest", true)) {
    doFirst {
        subprojects.each { project ->
           
            def unitTestResultFile = "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"

            if (file(unitTestResultFile).exists() && executionData != null) {
                executionData.setFrom(unitTestResultFile)
            }
        }
    }
}


Error content:
> The value for this file collection is final and cannot be changed.
```

Removing the doFirst block does not report an error but does not generate a report.

```
task jacocoTotalReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: project.getTasksByName("testDebugUnitTest", true)) {
 
        subprojects.each { project ->

            def unitTestResultFile = "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"

            if (file(unitTestResultFile).exists() && executionData != null) {
                executionData.setFrom(unitTestResultFile)
            }
        }
    
}
```